# Applying Markov's inequality to a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, limits, inequality, probability-distributions, expectation

Does the [Markov inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality) also work for infinite $a$ or only for constant $a$?

More precisely: If $X(n)$ is a sequence of random variables and $f(n)$ is some sequence of numbers,is it allowed to apply Markov inequality for $X(n)$ and $f(n)$ even though I know that $f(n) \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *more precise* part makes perfect sense: sure, for every $n$ you can apply Markov's inequality to $X(n)$ and $f(n)$ (assuming $X(n)$ is nonnegative),  obtaining
$$\mathbb P(X(n)\ge f(n))\le \frac{\mathbb E(X(n))}{f(n)}$$

The first sentence of your question is meaningless.  Applying some operation to every term in a sequence of numbers than tends to $\infty$ is not the same as applying the operation to $\infty$. The latter is often undefined.